# References to incomplete types

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

According to the C++03 standard, is it valid to have references to incomplete types? I'm not aware of any implementation that implements references as any other than non-null pointers, so such code ought to work. However, I wonder whether references to incomplete types are standard conforming.

I would appreciate answers with quotes and references to the C++ standard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The C++ standard doesn't explicitly say, as far as I know, that you can have a reference to an incomplete type. But the standard does have a section that specifies when a type *must* be complete:

> **3.2 One definition rule [basic.def.odr]**
>
> *4.* Exactly one definition of a class is required in a translation
>   unit if the class is used in a way that requires the class type to be
>   complete. [*Example:* the following complete translation unit is
>   well-formed, even though it never defines `X`:
>
> ```
>     struct X;     // declare X as a struct type
>     struct X* x1; // use X in pointer formation
>     X* x2;        // use X in pointer formation
> ```
>
> *—end example*] [*Note:* the rules for declarations and expressions
>   describe in which contexts complete class types are required. A class
>   type `T` must be complete if:
>
> - an object of type `T` is defined (3.1, 5.3.4), or
> - an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied to an lvalue referring to
>     an object of type `T` (4.1), or
> - an expression is converted (either implicitly or explicitly) to
>     type `T` (clause 4, 5.2.3, 5.2.7, 5.2.9, 5.4), or
> - an expression that is not a null pointer constant, and has type
>     other than `void *` is converted to the type pointer to `T` or reference
>     to `T` using an implicit conversion (clause 4), a `dynamic_cast` (5.2.7)
>     or a `static_cast` (5.2.9), or
> - a class member access operator is applied to an expression of type
>     `T` (5.2.5), or
> - the `typeid` operator (5.2.8) or the `sizeof` operator (5.3.3) is
>     applied to an operand of type `T`, or
> - a function with a return type or argument type of type `T` is defined
>     (3.1) or called (5.2.2), or
> - an lvalue of type `T` is assigned to (5.17). ]

It appears that in every other case, including declarations of references to incomplete types, the type can be incomplete.

Comment: Note that this list, while very useful, is in a non-normative note and thus does not _specify_ anything.  It's just helpful.

Answer (score 6):

§15.1.3 says

> The type of the throw-expression shall not be an incomplete type, or a
>   pointer or reference to an incomplete type, other than void*, const
>   void*, volatile void*, or const volatile void*.

Which seems to imply that you can have a reference to an incomplete type.

I'm not quite good at interpreting the standard yet, so take that how you will.