# C++ cyclic dependency confusion with adjacency list representation

Tags: c++, adjacency-list, cyclic-reference

Sorry for my inexperience with C++, but I spent quiet some time with solving a cyclic dependency issue and hence posing this.

I am trying to represent a Adjacency List in C++.

I have struct `Node`,

```
struct Node{

    int data;
    unordered_set<Node, Hash> links;

    bool operator == (Node const& other) const{
        return (data == other.data);
    }

    Node(){
    }

    Node(int data){
        this->data = data;
    }
};
```

and I have my `Hash` functor

```
struct Hash {
    size_t operator()(const Node &node) const {
        return node.data;
    };
};
```

I noticed that `Hash` uses `Node` and `Node` uses `Hash`
If for the purpose of this exercise I want to declare everything in a single file, which one should I declare first.

I tried forward declaration of both `Hash` and `Node` with defining either of them first, but none of them compiled.

PS: This is not homework, I'm trying to solve graph algorithm puzzles online

Comment: you can use vector< vector<> >  to store adjacency list. Will be a lot easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delay defining `Hash::operator()` until after defining `Node` and declare `Node` before `Hash`. You can have a reference to an incomplete type as long as you don't do anything with it.

```
class Node;

class Hash{
    public:
        size_t operator()(const Node &node) const;
};

class Node{
    public:
        int data;
        unordered_set<Node, Hash> links;
};

inline size_t Hash::operator()(const Node &node) const{
    return node.data;
}
```

Comment: Interestingly g++4.9/g++5 does not compile, complains about `Node` being an incomplete type, however clang++ does compile the code.

Comment: @vsoftco I think I saw a question on SO about this difference, and trying to figure out which of the two compilers is right, but I can't seem to find it, and I don't remember what was the answer.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight it seems the above code is UB, I just asked a question about this http://stackoverflow.com/q/28911009/3093378

Comment: @vsoftco [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7356603/references-to-incomplete-types) seems to suggest otherwise.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode I think the issue was clarified in the C++11 standard, not sure about C++03.

Answer (score 1):

Resolving the syntax by moving the implementation of hash to a point after the `Node` is fully defined is insufficient. No matter what the order is, you would not be able to compile it, because `unordered_set` of `Node` expects the `Node` to be a *complete type*, i.e. the type needs to be fully defined.

In addition to splitting out the definition of `Hash::operator()` you need to change the first type parameter of the `unordered_set` to a pointer, preferably a smart pointer:

```
unordered_set<shared_ptr<Node>, Hash> links;
...
size_t Hash::operator()(const shared_ptr<Node> &node) const{
    return node->data;
}
```

A regular pointer would also work, but then you would have to manage memory for your nodes separately - e.g. by placing all nodes in a vector.