# incomplete type for std::unordered_set compiling error in g++5, compiles in clang++

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, incomplete-type, gcc5

Consider the code related to a previous SO question [C++ cyclic dependency confusion with adjacency list representation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28910892/3093378)

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <unordered_set>

class Node;

class Hash {
public:
    std::size_t operator()(const Node &node) const;
};

class Node {
public:
    int data;
    std::unordered_set<Node, Hash> links;
};

inline size_t Hash::operator()(const Node &node) const {
    return node.data;
}

int main()
{

}
```

This code does not compile when using g++4.9.2 or g++5, however compiles with clang++3.5.

The error spit out by g++ starts with

> `error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'Node'`
>   `: std::aligned_storage<sizeof(_Tp), std::alignment_of<_Tp>::value>`

**Question:** Does `Node` have to be a complete type when declaring an `std::unordered_set`? Looks like either g++ or clang++ is wrong in this case.

PS: I know this situation can be avoided by using a `std::shared_ptr<Node>` instead, however would like to understand the behaviour in the code above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is undefined behavior to instantiate a standard library container with an incomplete type. [res.on.functions]/1, 2.5:

> 1 In certain cases (replacement functions, handler functions,
>   operations on types used to instantiate standard library template
>   components), the C++ standard library depends on components supplied
>   by a C++ program. If these components do not meet their requirements,
>   the Standard places no requirements on the implementation.
>
> 2 In particular, the effects are undefined in the following cases:
>
> - [...]
> - if an incomplete type (3.9) is used as a template argument when instantiating a template component, unless specifically allowed for
>     that component.

Both implementations are correct.

There is currently a [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4371.html) to add incomplete type support to some containers, but it is limited to `vector`, `list` and `forward_list`.

Comment: hmm, clang++ doesn't even spit a warning, `clang++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic so.cpp`

Comment: _ +1: I can't see anything to dispute this answer.

Comment: @T.C. thanks, spot on. I knew there were issues with `std::vector` from a quite old C++ article http://www.drdobbs.com/the-standard-librarian-containers-of-inc/184403814 , but didn't know that now the standard explicitly prohibits the use of incomplete types everywhere (unless specifically allowed).

Comment: @vsoftco it's not "everywhere", just as standard container contents.

Comment: @MattMcNabb [res.on.functions] applies everywhere.

Comment: @MattMcNabb "if an incomplete type (3.9) is used as a template argument when instantiating a template component, unless specifically allowed for that component." -- this seems to mean that it is everywhere. For `std::shared_ptr` etc, it is probably explicitly allowed to use incomplete types.

Comment: OK, I learned something. Does unique_ptr have that exception too? (If not then it couldn't be used for pImpls)