# resolve compilation failure due to use of incomplete type in a hash function

Tags: c++, hash

the following code failed to compile due to use of incomplete type Dir when compiling the hashing function for the unordered_set. is there a way to get around this. I'm guessing adding another class might solve this issue. But what is the optimal practice to resolve case like this.

```
auto pred = [](const auto& v) {
                return std::hash<std::string>()(v.name);
            };

struct Dir{
    bool operator==(Dir const& other) {
        return name == other.name;
    }

    std::string name;
    std::unordered_set<Dir, decltype(pred)> down;
};
```

Comment: Whats your compiler ?

Comment: I use g++ with c++ 17 flag

Comment: One way to resolve it is to store all child Dir pointers in a vector. then have an unordered_map to map from Dir name to vector iterator.

Comment: Weirdly the code you posted is working fine on Microsoft's Compiler

Comment: `std::vector` , `std::list` , and `std::forward_list` must support incomplete types per the standard (pretty sure that is the list of them). Anything else will be non-standard support.

Comment: For more details refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28911009/incomplete-type-for-stdunordered-set-compiling-error-in-g5-compiles-in-clan).

Answer (score 0):

This solves problem, uniquess, addition/removal of Dir are all taken care of, as it seems. but we need to track the list and unordered_map tightly to ensure it is working correctly. not sure if this is the best way to go.

```
struct Dir{
    std::string name;
    std::list<Dir> down;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::list<Dir>::iterator> downMap;
};
```

Comment: You can maintain two containers, some other options:
1. You can always just make it a `unique_ptr<Dir>`.
2. You can refactor it so that the type in the map isn't the same type as the struct holding the map.